# .htaccess (Object not found when URL has spaces)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1&type=$2 [L]
```

When I connect like *dummy.com/UsernameTest* it works perfectly fine, the problem is, when I connect with *dummy.com/Username Test* the URL changes the spaces to *%20* (as expected?) and I receive the Object Not Found(404) error. I've already tried *urldecode($_GET['user']);* in my PHP file, but I had the same problem.

Comment: Change `([\w-]+)` to `(.*?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your regex to allow spaces and also use `RewriteCond` to prevent looping:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?user=$1&type=$2 [L,QSA]
```